# How to rewrite this nested call to set using fat arrow es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In https://github.com/yeahoffline/redis-mock/blob/master/test/client/redis-mock.keys.test.js:

```
  beforeEach(function (done) {
    r.set("hello", "test", function () {
      r.set("hallo", "test", function () {
        r.set("hxlo", "test", done);
      });
    });
  });
```

What is the way to convert this to ES6 fat arrow syntax? I tried looking for an online converter but failed to find one.

Comment: Literally replace `function()` with `() =>`. For the first one, `done =>`

Comment: @Phil I think what he needs is a tool that does it automatically.

Comment: Arrow functions wouldn't reduce the nesting here, the nesting is because this code is using callbacks. To get rid of the nesting, one could util.promisify as mentioned in [the docs for the library redis-mock is mocking](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#promises).

Comment: @Raxel21 that is off-topic for StackOverflow. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2):

```
  beforeEach((done) => {
    r.set("hello", "test", () => {
      r.set("hallo", "test", () => {
        r.set("hxlo", "test", done);
      });
    });
  });
```

If it was a standalone function you would write

`const setHellos = (done) => { .... }`